# return a nested array from one function, pass as argument to another function

Tags: arrays, function, powershell, return, arguments

I'm exasperated, trying not to resort to using a $Global variable to pass variable,   I've seen the other seemingly identical "subjects" in this forum but in the details I am lost or it appears that they are doing something different - or I just don't understand the question or solution.

I am getting an array of event objects from a `Get-WinEvent` in func1.  I want to return that array and use it as an argument for another func2.
CASE#1

````
 $evtArray = Get-WinEvt -FilterHashtable @{ LogName=Application } #simplified for brevity
 return $evtArray  #not sure if working or not
 return ,$evtArray #not sure if working or not
 return @,$evtArray #not sure if working or not
}**```

```**function func2($evtArray) { #doesn't work
function func2( ,$evtArray ) #syntax error
function func2( ,($evtArray)) #syntax error
  ....further processing of the $evtArray occurs......**```

CASE#2 (may be the same as CASE#1 - not sure)
```**$array += ,(<date-time1>,[int],"string")
$array += ,(<date-time2>,[int],"string")**
....
Then pass $array as argument to a function
**func2($array)**
````

I've spent some hours on this and seen a dozen promising looking same subjects......

Comment: You don’t call functions using parenthesis. Call it like `Get-Something -SomeParameter $evtarray`

Comment: Right, old habits, I wasn't doing that in my code, func2 $array  or func2 ,$array or func2  ,(array)  .... this appears to a problem for a lot of people,    I see a lot of people with same questions but no clear answer.....

Comment: Your code is hard time o follow.  Where is func1?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you do not use return. It ends the current function and is generally unnecessary. To pass arguments to a function, do not enclose in parenthesis. The arguments should be space delimited and preferably you name the parameters, although that is not required.

```
$evtArray = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName='Application'; ID = 0}

Function func2($Array){
    $array.gettype()
}

func2 $evtArray
```

As I said before you don't have to name the parameter and instead use positional arguments, but best practice for scripts/modules is to use full names.

```
func2 -Array $evtArray
```

Output when called either way is

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                           
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                           
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Comment: Doug, Thank so much for your insight.    I'm a n00bie at powershell, but in your example $evtArray is global scope var and I am really trying to avoid doing that.....'function func1 { $evtArray = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName='Application'; ID = 0} return ,evt$array' 'function func2($tmparray) { .........} '  'func2 = func1'

Comment: Ok, here is what I have working....  I've seen some ways to pass  array as argument but they are complicated and the solutions appear to assume the reader knows a lot more about powershell than I do

Comment: ``function firstFunction {
    $array = 1,2,3
    return ,$array
}

function secondFunction {
    $tmpArray = firstFunction
    Write-Host $tmpArray
}`

Comment: News flash! I got this to work!   func2 @(func1)